# Qt export windows registry to a file

Tags: c++, windows, qt, registry

Could someone help to convert this **Windows command in a Qt C++ manner** :

```
REG EXPORT "HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName" "dest.reg"
::Exports all subkeys and values into a reg file recursively.
```

The sample registry tree with groups and subgroups to be exported :

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName]   
"Install"=dword:0000132c

[HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName\Association]

[HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName\Install] 
"Path"="C:\\path\\to\\dir"  "Send To"=dword:00000001

[HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName\Settings] 
"Explorer"=dword:00000000  "Toolbar"=dword:00000001

[HKCU\SOFTWARE\My-Software\SoftName\Settings\Custom 0]
"Explorer"=dword:00000000
```

As I'm quite new to C++ and Qt I'm trying hard with QSettings but i really wonder if it is the best way for making a registry export.

I just need a raw export (including even empty group names), no need to edit the datas.

Comment: Why not just use [RegSaveKey()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724917(v=vs.85).aspx) and leave Qt out of this?

Comment: Qt is for writing cross-platform code. If you're going to do something with the Windows registry, I hardly see any reason why that should be done with Qt (leave alone if that were possible). I'd go with what MrEricSir suggested - just use RegSaveKey or something from the Windows API.

Comment: I use Qt for it's quick and easy creation of windows and widgets, but I'll look at RegSaveKey() for doing the registry export, thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Finally I ended up the easiest way by **passing windows batch's command** in my C++ app. After trying many things without success.

**Sample code for executing a (windows) system command in C++:**

```
system("ANY_SYSTEM_COMMAND");
```

**And the code to export a registry part into a .reg file:**

```
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("REG EXPORT \"HKCU\\SOFTWARE\\My-Software\\SoftName\" \"destfile.reg\" ");

    return 0;
}
```

It's intended to run under windows system only.